# How to read JSON response from a REST API using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-services

I'm learning Angular basics. I've picked up a very small project. I'm using JSONPlaceholder, the fake REST API. I want to read all posts and render them on a the page using simple `ngFor` loop. I've created a service for that. I'll show my code one by one. But here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xlhe1) for the same.
I need help with these files only:

1. post-list
2. post interface
3. post.service

I've written this much code from the scratch after reading atricles and watching tutorials on pluralsight and youtube but now I'm blocked. Here's my code:

**post.ts**

```
export interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

**post.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {

  constructor() {}

  getAllPosts():Observable<Post[]> {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
  }
}
```

**post-list.component.ts**

```
import { PostService } from './post.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Post } from './post'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
})
export class PostList {

  posts: Post[] = [];
  errorMessage="";
  
  constructor(private postservice: PostService) {
    this.postservice.getAllPosts().subscribe({
      next: posts => {
        this.posts=posts;
      },
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
  }
}
```

I insist, please look at the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xlhe1) it will save everyone's time and efforts. My problems are:

> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
>
> Error:  0.9.1/dist/zone.j

Please point out my mistakes and correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should change your service and use `HttpClient` inside `HttpClientModule`.

```js
export class PostService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {};

  getAllPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Post[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  }
}
```

Becareful also to correctly import `HttpClientModule`, and `CommonModule` is you're using child modules. Common directives, like `async` won't be accessible if you don't import it.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:[
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
   ...
```

Then you have multiple options to retrieve and render your result, here are 2 main alternatives :

#### Option 1

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
})
export class PostList {
  posts: Post[] = [];
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private postService: PostService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.postService.getAllPosts().subscribe(
      posts => {
        this.posts = posts
      },
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = error;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

#### Option 2 (recommended)

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
})
export class PostList {
  posts$: Observable<Post[]>;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private postService: PostService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$ = this.postService.getAllPosts().pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.errorMessage = error;
      });
    );
  }
}
```

template.html :

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
  <p>{{ post.userId }}</p>
  ...
</div>
```

See [updated stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60797449how-to-read-json-response-from-a-rest-api-using-angu) for this recommended option with `Observable` and `async` pipe.

Comment: Sir I'm implementing Option 1, but I'm getting `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.`. I've saved changes in stackblitz can you please check it once more ?

Comment: Please read again my answer I updated it with at least 2 main points : see my stackblitz demo, and also take care to import `CommonModule`.